# How to link to user-uploaded profile pictures (ImageField) in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models

I have instances of this model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True) #Each User is related to only one User Profile
    prof_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pictures')
```

All the profile pictures are uploaded via population script in `django_project_folder/media/profile_pictures`

I have access to all the details inside the template via the context dictionary but I don't know what to put inside the image tag.

```
<img src=" what to put here?? " id="second" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

I tried linking the prof_pic via the context dictionary like this but it appeared broken:

```
<img src=" {{ req1.req1.traveler.profile.prof_pic }} " id="second" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

I looked at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) document but didn't know how to link media files in the template.

I have done the MEDIA_ROOT configuration and I already know how to link static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access the `prof_pic` attribute of a `UserProfile` model instance you get a `FieldFile` object back which has a [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) property. Try the following:

```
<img src="{{ req1.req1.traveler.profile.prof_pic.url }}" id="second" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

Further reading: [FileField and FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile).